# C++ generics field/property in a class

Tags: c++, class

I'm not sure how to build this out, but here is the basics.  I have a class that reads a file.  As it goes through, it has some things that are generically handled and for each "piece" (many pieces in a given file).  As each "piece" is processed, it's SPECIFIC type is identified and I want an instance of another class by the specific type to be added (via new *instance() of that class.  Here is the basics of what I'm trying to do.

This is the baseline I want to ultimately get to

```
class SpecificBaseline
{
   public:
      SpecificBaseline();
      virtual void ThisHandledPerDerived();
}

Specific subclassed instances
class SubClass1 : SpecificBaseline
{ -- blah -- }

class AnotherSubClass : SpecificBaseline
{ -- blah -- }

class SubSub1 : AnotherSubClass
{ -- blah -- }
```

Here is the simple PerPiece instance that is detecting which TYPE (per above class/subclasses) it should represent / operate like.

```
class OnePiece
{
   public:
      ReadSpecificType(string *s);

   protected:
      [AnyDerivedFromSpecificBaseline] specificType;
}

OnePiece::ReadSpecificType(string *s)
{
   if string contains (whatever)
      specificType = new WhichSubClassDerivedFromSpecificBaseline();
   else if another expected key
      specificType = new DifferentSubClassDerivedFromSpecificBaseline();
   else
      etc...
}
```

I was even considering generics such as

```
<typename T>
class MyClass<T>
{
   blah...
}
```

and building an array of pointers for each type, but not sure how to properly create the pointer when it could be of any type of the desired "SpecificBaseline".

Any help, or even alternative solutions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a factory method `ReadSpecificType`. Make all the specific types inherit from a common base class and create a factory method that takes as argument the string to be parsed and returns a point to the common base class.

Comment: I thought about the factory process, but I guess what I'm missing is the declaration of the property, and how to apply the new creation.  As per the example, I already DO have the classes of the specific type but was getting compile errors of cant change from type [x] to [y] where x was the top-level, and y was a derived class.

Comment: @DRapp maybe you are confused from other languages. In C++ you can have polymorphism either with pointers or with references(T&). That is why I propose you return a **pointer** to the base class.

Comment: Thanks, and I've looked into factory samples but couldn't get it mentally through my head (but that was last night about 11:30 :).  Anyhow, I'll get back to my project later tonight when I return home.